# c# distribute code first application with localdb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, localdb

I'm doing a c# database application using EF code first. When I call DBContext it will create database in localdb (which I have in a folder in Users/... on my machine).

But what will happen if I want to "distribute" my application (by sharing my zipped solution or just my .exe)?

Will the connection to my database be available?

How can I make it available on client's machine?

I don't care about the data inside the database, since every machine needs to build its own data. I'm just wondering what can I do if my program will run on a machine that doesn't have SQLlocaldb installed on.

Comment: If the application relies upon a DB, then you will need to ensure that every machine running the application has access to a DB.  That could either be a centralized DB installed on a server or in the cloud, or it could be LocalDb / SQL / SQLExpress installed on each machine.  It is unlikely that "your database" will be accessible to every client, especially if it is your development environment.

Comment: @Claies Exactly what I was thinking. But, assume I would like to go for the second option (LocalDb installed on each machine), how can I do this? Could you suggest an example or tutorial? I'm a beginner

Comment: the binaries for localdb are available from Microsoft at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299.  Select either the Localdb 64 bit or 32 bit installer for the machine you are deploying to.

Comment: @Claies Ok, but I don't know which machine is getting my application. Is there a "in-application" method to install localdb on my application first run?

Comment: depends on how you deploy your app.  normally you would build a deployment project, either click once, wix, install shield, etc, which would take care of ensuring all your prerequisites are installed.

Comment: @Claies How ca I include localdb install in install shield or wix??

Comment: I don't use either of those products, but I would assume it isn't terribly difficult to include prerequisites, there are thousands of applications in the world that do it.....

Comment: You will have to add the User to the database as well, if your connection string contains "trusted Connection=Yes". So, before deploying, you have to know the machine\user for that machine and add it in your database.